# how to resize an iframe to fit the enclosing panel

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3 for this.

I have an **iframe** element inside a **p:panel** which is enhanced with a **p:resizable** component.  What I want is to automatically resize the **iframe** on load and on resize event so that it fits the available width and height of the panel.

Note that in this example, there is a **p** element with some text in it before the **iframe**.  So the relative origin of the **iframe** isn't a constant.

Here is the template code:

```
            <h1>Page To Test Stuff</h1>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                function doIFrame(event, ui) {
                    var frame = document.getElementById("tFrame");
                    // now what?
                }
            </script>

            <p:panel id="showit">
                <p>
                    What I need is for the following iFrame (id="tFrame") to
                    automatically resize to the max available space inside 
                    the surrounding panel.  This needs to happen when the
                    window is initially drawn, and when the user clicks and
                    drags the resize icon.
                </p>
                <iframe id="tFrame" 
                        src="http://www.apple.com" 
                        />
            </p:panel>
            <p:resizable for="showit" onStop="doIFrame(event, ui)"/>
```

My Javascript proficiency sucks but I am willing to learn. So I don't need more than a clue to get started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the element's client width and height by [`element.clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientWidth) and [`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientHeight). You can set the element's width and height by assigning `element.width` and `element.height`.

So, this should basically do it (roughly; I'm taking panel's default ~20px padding into account and I also assume that you removed that introductory `<p>`, else you have to take its client height into account as well):

```
var panel = document.getElementById("showit");
var frame = document.getElementById("tFrame");
frame.width = panel.clientWidth - 40;
frame.height = panel.clientHeight - 40;
```

Comment: OK, I'll start with this.  I suspect that before I'm finished I will have to dig into the structure that the p:panel builds to remove that "40" constant.   I did want the iframe to share the panel with the other text, but if I can't figure out how to do that I will live without it.

Comment: settign iframe width: 100% works for me, however height does not adjust and the javascript is necessary for it.