# Ext JS : resizing panel to fit an outer region

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, extjs

I have a tree panel and I have to fit it into a Viewport's region, the region is resizable.
The region contains an Iframe, the tree panel is created in this Iframe.
(In other words the region and tree panel are generated in two different HTML pages).

Using the "layout: 'fit'" attribute in the tree panel doesn't work properly, as the tree panel isn't fit once I resize the region.

Is it somehow possible?

Comment: It's tricky though, as you might want to resize the iframe explicitly.  Is there any chance you can avoid the use of iframe? If not, this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677460/how-to-resize-an-iframe-to-fit-the-enclosing-panel?rq=1 might help

Answer (score 0):

the layout:'fit' attribute should be set on your region's config, not on your tree panel. Then the tree panel should be place as an item of your region. Try also to set anchor: '100%' on your tree panel.